# how can i change imagebuttons automatically after what users want?

Tags: java, android

I making an app which you can use to start other apps like Netflix on. I have four imagebuttons on the first XML file which is going to be the "Favorites". When you click on any of these imagebuttons you start the intent for the app you wanted to start. Then the app gets opened. How can I make it so that the Favorites changes automatically after what the user uses.

Here is my Java Code:

```
    package com.carlo_projekt.tvprograms;
    
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Locale;

'    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton speakBtn;
    Button CategoriesBtn;

    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        speakBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.SpeakImageBtn);
        CategoriesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CategoriesBtn);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }


    public void OpenGame(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MoreActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void Speak(View view)
    {
        Intent recognizeIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        recognizeIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        recognizeIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
        recognizeIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hi! Which app do you want to start?");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(recognizeIntent, 1);

        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException a)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry! Your device doesn't support this function!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int request_Code, int result_Code, Intent recognizeIntent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(request_Code, result_Code, recognizeIntent);
        switch (request_Code)
        {
            case 1: if(result_Code == RESULT_OK && recognizeIntent != null)
            {
                ArrayList<String> result = recognizeIntent.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                for(int i = 0; i<result.size(); i++)
                {
                    result.set(i, result.get(i).toLowerCase());

                    if(result.get(i).compareTo("start netflix") == 0)
                    {
                        Intent NetflixIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.netflix.mediaclient");
                        startActivity(NetflixIntent);
                    }

                    else if(result.get(i).compareTo("start youtube") == 0)
                    {
                        Intent NetflixIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
                        startActivity(NetflixIntent);
                    }

                    else if(result.get(i).compareTo("start viafree") == 0)
                    {
                        Intent NetflixIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("se.viafree.android");
                        startActivity(NetflixIntent);
                    }

                    else if(result.get(i).compareTo("start tvfour") == 0)
                    {
                        Intent NetflixIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("se.tv4.tv4playtab");
                        startActivity(NetflixIntent);
                    }

                    else if(result.get(i).compareTo("start dplay") == 0)
                    {
                        Intent NetflixIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("se.kanal5play");
                        startActivity(NetflixIntent);
                    }

                    else if(result.get(i).compareTo("start viaplay") == 0)
                    {
                        Intent NetflixIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.viaplay.android");
                        startActivity(NetflixIntent);
                    }

                    else if(result.get(i).compareTo("start svtplay") == 0)
                    {
                        Intent NetflixIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("se.svt.android.svtplay");
                        startActivity(NetflixIntent);
                    }
                    /**text.setText(result.get(i));*/
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void OpenApps(String packageName)
    {
        if(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName) != null)
        {
            Intent tv4PlayIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            startActivity(tv4PlayIntent);
        }
        else
        {

        String marketAppPackageName = "market://details?id="+ packageName;
        MessageBox(marketAppPackageName);

        }
    }

    public void NetflixFunction(View view)
    {
        String netflixPackageName = new String("com.netflix.mediaclient");
        OpenApps(netflixPackageName);
    }

    public void ViafreeFunction(View view)
    {
        String viafreePackageName = new String("se.viafree.android");
        OpenApps(viafreePackageName);
    }

    public void YoutubeFunction(View view)
    {
        String youtubePackageName = new String("com.google.android.youtube");
        OpenApps(youtubePackageName);
    }

    public void Tv4PlayFunction(View view)
    {
        String tv4playPackageName = new String("se.tv4.tv4playtab");
        OpenApps(tv4playPackageName);
    }



    public void LayoutsShow(View view)
    {
        RelativeLayout layoutShow = findViewById(R.id.LayoutShow);

        if (layoutShow.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            layoutShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        else if (layoutShow.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            layoutShow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public void MessageBox(final String uriIntent)
    {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Couldn't find this app");
        String messageText = "We cant find this app, do you want to download it?";
        alertDialog.setMessage(messageText);

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent MarketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        MarketIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uriIntent));
                        startActivity(MarketIntent);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }}
```

This is my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    tools:context="com.carlo_projekt.tvprograms.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CategoriesBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
            android:onClick="OpenGame"
            android:text="Categories"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/NetflixImageBtn"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/CategoriesBtn"
            android:onClick="NetflixFunction"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/netflix" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/YoutubeImageBtn"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/NetflixImageBtn"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CategoriesBtn"
            android:onClick="YoutubeFunction"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/youtube" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ViafreeImageBtn"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/NetflixImageBtn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NetflixImageBtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:onClick="ViafreeFunction"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/viafree" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Tv4PlayImageBtn"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/YoutubeImageBtn"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ViafreeImageBtn"
            android:onClick="Tv4PlayFunction"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/tv4" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/SpeakImageBtn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:onClick="Speak"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/microphone" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton19"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sweden" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton24"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton19"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/great_britain" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton22"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton24"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/germany" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton23"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton22"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/france" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton25"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton23"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/spanish" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="193dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="217dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#ff00" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
`
```

I'm pretty new with stack overflow so I hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can create a button that sets the app and get the apps package from a chooser, then use that package to get the apps icon from the 'PackageManager' and give that drawable to the imagebutton. Then after keeping track of that package, start it in the intent

Comment: But i want to make so it checks what the user uses most and changes after that. Like a checker that allways listen to witch app who starting from this app.

Comment: Add a click listener to your buttons. When a button is clicked, capture the ID and increment the count in SharedPreferences.

Comment: Okey, that sounds good! Thanks for the help! I will try this!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try this!

Comment: @heath3n can you help me to write some code just so i can see how you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get SharedPreferences object:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Create a click listener that will update the click count for the appropriate button:

```
View.OnClickListener myClickListener= new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String tag = (String) v.getTag();
        sharedPref
             .edit()
             .putInt(tag, shardPref.getInteger(tag) + 1)
             .apply();
    }
};
```

Now for each of your buttons, you will want to set both the click listener and a tag for naming purposes:

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.NetflixImageBtn);
btn.setTag("netflix");
btn.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
```

Now when you click a button, it will increment the count associated with the tag. You can use that information however you wish.

Comment: okey thanks. But how do i change packagename and picture to the imagebutton. like if a button have more clicks it would change place from one imagebutton to another.

Comment: I want to make like four imagebuttons who can open diffrent apps but witch app it will open depends on wich app who is most used. For example, if i open netflix from this app like 10 times and i only open yoitube 3 times, then they will change place with each other.

Comment: You should lay your buttons out programmatically then, not by hardcoding them in the XML. Sort the list of buttons to create by the click count, and then add them to the layout.

Comment: How can i write that code in java code? Im new to android studio so i only knows how to do it trough XML

Comment: No problem. If your problem is solved, please use the checkmark to mark it as such. If you have further questions, please ask.